# Couldn't create a new database in Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, command-line

I just installed PostgresSql in my Ubuntu 20.04, and I started to work with it. I learned that I can enter the psql shell by typing `sudo -u postgres psql`, and I was able to execute some commands such as `/q, /l, /d, /du`, etc.

I was following a tutorial on how to create a postgres database and manipulate it using TypeORM, and the tutorial uses `createdb <DB_NAME>` to create a new database. I tried to do it on my terminal, as showed in the tutorial, and I got an error that says:

```
createdb testdb

createdb: error: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  role "gabriel" does not exist
```

Edit:

I tried to create a database in the psql shell using CREATE DATABASE testdb, but when i type /l to list my db's, testdb is not there

Comment: What tutorial? You can `CREATE DATABASE` in `psql` using [CREATE DATABASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html).

Comment: If you want to `createdb` then; `sudo -u postgres createdb testdb`. The issue is that `createdb testdb` without  `-U` is going to run as the system user, in this case `gabriel` which alos in this case is not a role in the database.